# Ingresar Objeto en un Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, array, objeto

Que tal comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con esta aplicacion que me encuentro realizando.... es una aplicacion para agregar nombres de musica a una lista de musica pero me encuentro con un problema... y es que al momento de querer insertar un nuevo objeto (nuevaCancion) en el array de mi codigo, no me deja ya que no me agrega otro objeto solo lo sobreescribe del que ya ingrese cuando lo ingreso en el formulario en el segundo intento y me doy cuenta al momento de imprimir el mensaje al dar click al finalizar el formulario en que me estoy equivocando? Anexo codigo abajo:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", capturar);

 
function capturar(){
     
     //Objetos
    function cancion(id,nombre){
    
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
    
    
    }
     
     
     campoId = document.getElementById("id").value;
     campoNombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
     


    nuevaCancion = new cancion(campoId,campoNombre);
    
     agregar();
 }




//Arreglos

let lista =[];



//funciones

function agregar(){
    lista.push(nuevaCancion);
    alert(JSON.stringify(lista));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    
</head>
<body>
    
    
   
    <div>
        
        <form>
              <label for="id">Id:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="id" name="id"><br>
  
              <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br><br>
              
              
              <input type="submit"  id="submit">
       </form> 
        
    </div>


        <script src="listaDeMusica.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrias explicarte mejor? A que te refieres por `no ingresa`, el codigo funciona correctamente

Comment: ya lo modifique, me refiero que no me guarda un nuevo objeto en el array, solo me sobre escribe el objeto en el segundo intento de ingresar un objeto @JuanRivera

Comment: Eso es porque tienes el evento `submit` por lo que redirigira a una nueva pagina en blanco por defecto (Porque no le envias el `action-form`), cosa que es como si recargaras la pagina. Por eso no te guarda, solo cambia el `type="submit"` por `type="button"`

Comment: Gracias Crack!! ya me funciono @JuanRivera